# Странное поведение компилятора

Tags: c#, нейронные-сети

Долго искал где баг в моей "нейронной сети", потом нашел

```
        using (Bitmap pixels = BitmapImage2Bitmap(image))
        {
            List<byte> b = new List<byte>();
            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
                { b.Add(pixels.GetPixel(x, y).B); inputNeureons[x, y].SetInput(pixels.GetPixel(x, y).B); }
        }
```

Вот класс нейрона:

```
    public class InputNeuron 
{
    System.Windows.Point coord { set; get; }
    float value { set; get; }
    int[] weight { set; get; }  // от -100 до 100

    public InputNeuron(System.Windows.Point coord) 
    {
        this.coord = coord;
        weight = new int[MainWindow.COUNT];
        for (int i = 0; i < MainWindow.COUNT; i++) weight[i] = 0;
    }
    // SET
    public void SetInput(byte number) { value = -((1/255)*number) + 1; } // 0..255
    public void SetWeight(int index, int value) { weight[index] = value > 100 ? 100 : value < -100 ? -100 : value; }
    // GET
    public System.Windows.Point GetCoord() { return coord; }
    public int GetWeight(int index) { return weight[index]; }
    public float GetInput() { return value; }
}
```

При вызове функции `SetInput(byte)`, у нейрона должно устанавливаться соответствующее `value`. По графику функции, если в функцию передадим 255, то `value` будет 0, если передадим 0, то `value` будет 1

Долго искал баг и дебажил, и вот понял, что `pixels.GetPixel(x, y).B` даёт корректное значение, тут видно какое (на количество элементов в `b` не обращайте внимания):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но value во ВСЕХ `InputNeureon` будет равно 1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как это так получается и как это решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это вот `1/255` всегда 0. Вы делите целое число, на целое, что ожидали получить? Если нужно вещественное число, то нужно писать `1.0/255`, т.е. мы явно указываем, что один из аргументов выражения является вещественным, «поднимая» всё выражение до вещественного числа.

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало. Глупая была ошибка